# How to create global variables in a Grails project

Tags: grails

What's the best practice of making a variable that would be accessible by almost all classes in a Grails project? Is there a config file that I can use for storage of that data (i.e. application.properties)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Your best bet is Config.groovy. Any class can access ConfigurationHolder.getConfig() which makes it global, and you can even have environment-specific values of your variable.

```
someVar = "foo"

environments {
   production {
      grails.serverURL = "http://www.changeme.com"
      someOtherVar = 1000
   }
   development {
      grails.serverURL = "http://localhost:8080/${appName}"
      someOtherVar = 100
   }
   test {
      grails.serverURL = "http://localhost:8080/${appName}"
      someOtherVar = 0
   }
}
```

Comment: great! just tested it and indeed it's working. just adding the info on  how to get the 'someVar' value: String var = ConfigurationHolder.getConfig().getProperty('someVar'). again, thanks a lot!

Comment: In Groovy you can use the aliased import "import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.ConfigurationHolder as CH" and then access it as "CH.config.someVar"

Comment: I tried this today and it says "ConfigurationHolder is deprecated" should I use it anyway or is there a new better way?

Comment: You can add a dependency injection for `def grailsApplication` to your controller/service/etc. and access the config via `grailsApplication.config`. For the rare cases where this won't work see http://burtbeckwith.com/blog/?p=993 and http://burtbeckwith.com/blog/?p=1017

Answer (score 4):

**With Grails 2.2**

```java
//In Config.groovy
myVar = '/My/Root/Images/Folder'

//In your Services/Controllers/etc..  
import grails.util.Holders
def grailsApplication = Holders.getGrailsApplication()

//access you variable
def myVar =  grailsApplication.config.myVar;
```