# How to extend per environment configuration in grails

Tags: grails, environment, config

It seems that only grails.serverURL and grails.path are recognized as per environment configrautions. bla and foo are ignored and could not be used in application
Anyone could solves this and provide a way to get bla and foo configured per environment?

```
environments {
    production {
        grails.serverURL = "http://alpha.foo.de"
        grails.path = ""
        bla = "text"
        foo= "word"
    }
    test {
        grails.serverURL = "http://test.foo.de"
        grails.path = ""
        bla = "othertext"
        foo= "otherword"
    }
}
```

Comment: How are accessing blah and foo? Can you post some code which is returning nothing for those properties?

Comment: how do you access this blah and foo from a Service? it doesn't work with grailsApplication.config.blah...

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2636796/how-to-create-global-variables-in-a-grails-project) question.

Answer (score 2):

Since Grails 3.0, both Groovy or YAML syntax can be used. The new main application configuration file is `/conf/application.yml` but you can continue to use your existing groovy configuration defining a `/conf/application.groovy` file.

This is an example of datasource definition per environment (in YAML):

```
environments:
    development:
        dataSource:
            dbCreate: create-drop
            url: jdbc:h2:mem:devDb
    test:
        dataSource:
            dbCreate: update
            url: jdbc:h2:mem:testDb
    production:
        dataSource:
            dbCreate: update
            url: jdbc:h2:prodDb
    myenv:
        dataSource:
            dbCreate: update
            url: jdbc:h2:myenvDb
```

To run a grails command in a specific environment  you can use:

```
grails [environment] [command name]
```

To target an environment different from dev, test and prod you can use:

```
grails -Dgrails.env=myenv run-app
```

See the [grails environment documentation](https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/conf.html#environments) or [this example application](https://github.com/grails-samples/grailstwitter/tree/master/grails-app/conf) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

All the ConfigSlurper variables are scoped by environment. What you've shown above should work fine.

When you use `grails run-app`, you are running in the `development` environment by default. Could that be your issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try...

```
> grails prod run-app
```

This should give you bla (text) and foo (word)

```
> grails test run-app
```

This should give you bla (othertext) and foo (otherword)

Answer (score 0):

Config.groovy setting

```
environments {
    development {
        grails.serverURL = "http://alpha.foo.de"
        grails.path = "/bar"
        staticServerURL = "http://static.foo.de"
        staticPath = "/static"
    }
}
```

source code index.gsp

```
${grailsApplication.config.staticServerURL}a
${grailsApplication.config.staticPath}b
${grailsApplication.config.grails.serverURL}c
${grailsApplication.config.grails.path}d
```

what is printed out when started with grails run-app

```
a b http://alpha.foo.dec /bard
```

Answer (score 0):

Check in your Config.groovy that you have the import for Environment

```
import grails.util.Environment
```

Otherwise the Environment.current is empty.